# threading.timer does not get closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

My code is similar to below:

```py
from tkinter import *
from threading import Timer

root = Tk()
###
def print_data():
    Timer(1.0, lambda: print_data()).start()
    data.set('sdsds')
###
data = StringVar()
data_label = Label(root, bg = '#FFF', textvariable = data)
data_label.pack()

timer = Timer(1.0, lambda: print_data());timer.start()
root.mainloop()
```

This raises `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop`.

What I tried:

```py
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: timer.cancel())          (close button will not work)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: 1. print_data is a function, print_data() is a function call, lambda: print_data() disguises the function call as a function -> redundant
2. You are recursively starting Timers inside print_data.

Comment: `tkinter` does not support multithreading, and your timer thread attempts to change something related to it in the main thread where its `mainloop()` is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tkinter` doesn't support multithreading in the sense that only one thread in a multithreaded application can use it. Your timer thread breaks that rule and attempts to change the value of the `StringVar` named `data` while the `mainloop()` is running in the main thread.

I don't understand everything your code is trying to accomplish, but the following shows how to do something very similar and avoids the `RuntimeError` by periodically polling a global flag every 500 ms to see if the `print_data()` function has ran.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP 8 preferred style.
from threading import Timer

def print_data():
    global printed
    global timer

    printed = True
    timer = Timer(1.0, print_data)
    timer.start()

def check_printed():
    global printed

    if printed:
        data.set('sdsds')
        printed = False
    root.after(500, check_printed)  # Check again in 500 ms.


root = tk.Tk()

data = tk.StringVar()
data_label = tk.Label(root, bg='#FFF', textvariable=data)
data_label.pack()

timer = Timer(1.0, print_data)
timer.start()

printed = False
check_printed()  # Start polling flag.

def shutdown():
    """Orderly app shutdown."""
    if timer.is_alive():
        timer.cancel()
    root.destroy()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", shutdown)
root.mainloop()

print('fini')
```